# Point game object to another only on the Local X Axis

Tags: unity-game-engine, vector, rotation, gameobject

I would like to have a Gameobject point to another only on the Local X-axis.

```
         void FixedUpdate()
         {
             if(started){
                 Vector3 targetPosition = target.position;
                 Vector3 direction = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(targetPosition - transform.position, transform.right);
                 Quaternion lookRot = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction, transform.right);
                 transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, lookRot, Time.fixedDeltaTime * 45);
             }
```

On the y-axis it worked with **transform.up** instead of **transform.right**, but on the x-axis the Gameobject only rotates permanently around the z-axis.

Comment: `transform.right = direction;` would work

Comment: It doesn't work properly because the object should rotate to a UFO on a planet. But the object to rotate is spawned at random positions on the planet and should always rotate in the direction of the UFO on the local X axis. The object gets the correct rotation at the beginning when it is spawned and should then only adjust its local X axis. Thanks anyway for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
Vector3 beforeRot = transform.eulerAngles;
transform.LookAt(gameObjectToLookAt.transform);
transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(transform.localEulerAngles.x, beforeRot.y, beforeRot.z);
```

1. This will take a record of the position before looking at the object.
2. Make it look at the object.
3. Reset rotation back to its original except the X rotation

Comment: It doesn't work properly because the object should rotate to a UFO on a planet. But the object to rotate is spawned at random positions on the planet and should always rotate in the direction of the UFO on the local X axis. The object gets the correct rotation at the beginning when it is spawned and should then only adjust its local X axis.   Thanks anyway for your answer